# wglCreateContext GetLastError() 0xc007001f

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I have an application that opens many windows. Sometimes, I get wglCreateContext() returns 0 and GetLastError() returns 0xc007001f.

It happens on Intel graphic cards only.

Did someone see it? Someone knows what it is?

Answer (score 4):

You can decompose the error code into its parts.  0xC makes it a fatal error, 007 produces facility code 7 which is the winapi.  Which makes the last four digits Windows error 31:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_GEN_FAILURE
//
// MessageText:
//
// A device attached to the system is not functioning.
//
#define ERROR_GEN_FAILURE                31L
```

Which makes it a pretty basic device driver kind of problem, assuming you passed a correct device context handle to wglCreateContext().  The kind that typically requires a video driver update and ensuring that the right kind of OpenGL driver is installed.  Nothing you can do to fix of course, this is a problem that the user needs to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe error 0xc007001f is when `SetPixelFormat()` fails. Which means, you are trying to use some feature in the pixel format that isn't supported by that card. If I'm not mistaken, Intel graphics cards barely support OpenGL (only [EDIT: 2.1]).

Comment: all latest cards support at least 2.1

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I haven't used Intel for graphics in a long time I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use FormatMessage to get string for error description:

```
DWORD err = GetLastError();
char* msg;
FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, 0, err, 0, (LPCSTR)&msg, 0, 0);
MessageBoxA(0, msg, "Error", 0);
LocalFree(msg);
```